# Trouble re-downloading paid Apple apps bundled for free with new Mac

Tags: apple-inc

I recently bought a 13" retina MacBook Pro. I set it up with my Apple ID. I subsequently changed my Apple ID password on my iPhone. When I came back to log into the MacBook, it wouldn't let me with my new password. So I tired my old password which didn't work as well. I performed a factory restore on it and that seemed to work. But I then noticed that it deleted certain apps that where already installed on the computer such as iMovie. When I go to the Mac App Store to re-download them, they are shown as paid apps.

How do I download them again for free?

Comment: If you log in with your Apple ID on the App Store there's a Purchased section where you should be able to download iMovie, iPhoto and so on

Answer (score 2):

To obtain the paid apps that were included for free with your Mac, launch the Mac App Store and login with your Apple ID. Check under the **Updates** section and see if the apps appear there, with **Accept** appearing where the **Update** button normally would be (towards the right).

If you cannot access them that way, check your purchases by going to the **Purchases** section in the Mac App store. They must have already been linked to your Apple ID.

If both the above options fail, open a case with [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/). They can verify your ownership of the computer and can issue download codes and/or link the purchase to your Apple ID. That way, you will be able to retrieve them for free.